# List of lists in Python -> Getting wrong output

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to print a list of lists from a loop, but getting the wrong output!
The last list that is appended to the bigger list is repeating.

The Output I'm expecting:

```
FINAL LIST:
[[(1, 2), (2, 3)],
 [(2, 3), (3, 4)]]
```

The Output I get:

```
FINAL LIST:
[[(2, 3), (3, 4)],
 [(2, 3), (3, 4)]]
```

What am I doing wrong here? Here's my code:

```
a = []
count = 1

#Function that generates some nos. for the list
def func():

    del a[:]
    for i in range(count,count+2):
        x = i
        y = i+1
        a.append((x,y))
    print '\nIn Function:',a    #List seems to be correct here
    return a


#List of lists
List = []
for i in range(1,3):
    b = func()             #Calling Function
    print 'In Loop:',b     #Checking the value, list seems to be correct here also
    List.append(b)
    count = count+1


print '\nList of Lists:'
print List
```

Comment: What do you think `del a[:]` does?

Comment: del a[:] empties the inner list every time I call the function, so that new set of tuples can be added

Comment: Yes, it only empties the list. But it's still the same container, each function call is modifying the same object. So, in the end `List` contains two references to the list `a`. Simply declare `a` as a local variable.

Comment: `del a[:]` doesn't make any sense. It creates a new copy of the list and then immediately deletes it.

Comment: @twasbrillig no, it doesn't. `del a[:]` simply *empties* `a`. It's mutation, not reassignment.

Comment: @twasbrillig No, it simply removes all items from `a`.

Comment: Ah, that's right. OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `del a[:]` statement. The rest of the code is fine. instead of doing that, put an empty `a` list in the beginning of the function and the problem disappears:

```
count = 1

#Function that generates some nos. for the list
def func():
    a = []
    for i in range(count,count+2):
        x = i
        y = i+1
        a.append((x,y))
    print '\nIn Function:',a    #List seems to be correct here
    return a


#List of lists
List = []
count = 1
for i in range(1,3):
    b = func()             #Calling Function
    print 'In Loop:',b     #Checking the value, list seems to be correct here also
    List.append(b)
    count = count + 1


print '\nList of Lists:'
print List
```

Answer (score 1):

You're appending the same list (`a`) to `List` multiple times (which you can see with `print List[0] is List[1]`). You need to create multiple lists instead, as in this example:

```
l = []
for i in xrange(3):
    l.append([i, i+1])
print l
```